# on a 404, redirect modifying the domain name

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, spring-oauth2

Have the UI hosted on example.com and backend hosted on api.example.com
In a specific OAuth scenario api.example.com returns a 404 for this url

`https://api.example.com/ng/login?error=access_denied&state=bQ9lk2#`

I would like to handle this 404 in nginx and redirect it to

`https://example.com/ng/login?error=access_denied&state=bQ9lk2#` [without the **api** subdomain]

How do I do this preserving the query params

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was easier to handle the redirect in app server itself. Left nginx alone.